# Getting compilation error while building a project

Tags: selenium, sikuli

I am working on Selenium webdriver. For Adobe flash player , I have implemented a jar named sikuli-setup.jar.
But getting compilation error while building the project.

```
/C:/prim_new/connect-selenium/src/main/java/com/selenium/automated/CreateLSMasterAssignment.java:[9,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
/C:/prim_new/connect-selenium/src/main/java/com/selenium/sikulihelper/CreateLSMasterAssignmentHelper.java:[4,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
/C:/prim_new/connect-selenium/src/main/java/com/selenium/automated/CreateLSMasterAssignment.java:[53,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Screen
  location: class com.selenium.automated.CreateLSMasterAssignment
/C:/prim_new/connect-selenium/src/main/java/com/selenium/automated/CreateLSMasterAssignment.java:[53,49] cannot find symbol
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error says it all: "package org.sikuli.script does not exist"

`Screen` is in `org.sikuli.api.Screen`. The jars that I use in my project are sikuli-api.jar, which has a dependency on sikuli-core.jar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Did you mean to say that I need to add sikuli-api.jar and sikuli-core jar both...??
Can you please provide me those two jars..??